# Jmeter software tester

Tags: testing, powerpoint, jmeter, detailsview

which box method is used in Jmeter tester(black box/ white box)?

what are the future enhancement of this tester?

give me methodes and techniques of JMeter tester?

how it is better than any other software tester??

Comment: And who killed the Kennedy? :)

Comment: plz tell me if u kw correct answers...help plz....bt soon.....

Answer (score 3):

JMeter do blackbox performance testing.
For full project info see http://jmeter.apache.org/, they have no public roadmap or plans.
Start with their wiki, there's a lot of information and links: http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/

There's still discussions what is better: JMeter, QTP, LoadRunner etc. Make peace, not holywar :)

Comment: thanks a lot.....i hv to give presentation on JMeter on monday so why in hurry nwys thanks a lot...:-)